# Invoke direct methods or methods with arguments / variables / parameters in EL

Tags: jsf, methods, arguments, parameter-passing, el

How can I in JSF 2.0 invoke direct methods or methods with arguments / variables / parameters in EL?

For example, getting the list size in EL:

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.list.size()}" />
```

Or invoking an action method with arguments:

```
<h:commandButton value="edit" action="#{bean.edit(item)}" />
```

This does not seem to work in my environment. It doesn't seem to like parentheses.

> javax.el.ELException: Error Parsing: #{bean.list.size()}
>   com.sun.el.parser.ParseException: Encountered "("

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206161/

Answer (score 55, accepted):

In standard EL prior to [EL 2.2 from Java EE 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html) you cannot directly invoke methods like
`#{bean.method()}` nor invoke methods with arguments like `#{bean.method(arg1, arg2)`.

If upgrading to a EL 2.2 / Java EE 6 compliant container (Tomcat 7, Glassfish 3, JBoss AS 6, etc) is not an option and you're currently using EL 2.1 / Java EE 5 (Tomcat 6, Glassfish 2, JBoss AS 4, etc), then your best bet is to install [JBoss EL](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/latest-2.2/reference/en-US/html/elenhancements.html). JBoss EL is an EL 2.1 compliant implementation which supports the same features as EL 2.2. Installing JBoss EL is a matter of putting the  [`jboss-el.jar`](https://maven.atlassian.com/content/repositories/jboss-releases/org/jboss/seam/jboss-el/2.0.0.GA/jboss-el-2.0.0.GA.jar) in `/WEB-INF/lib` and adding the following to the `web.xml`, assuming that you're using Mojarra:

```
<context-param>     
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
    <param-value>org.jboss.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>   
</context-param>
```

Or, when you're using MyFaces:

```
<context-param>     
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.EXPRESSION_FACTORY</param-name>
    <param-value>org.jboss.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>   
</context-param>
```

An alternative for *your particular case* is to use JSTL's [`fn:length`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/length.fn.html):

```
<h:outputText value="#{fn:length(bean.list)}" />
```

Another alternative is to add a getter to the bean which returns `List#size()` or in some specific cases a [custom EL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079978/how-to-create-a-custom-el-function/7080174#7080174).

---

Please note thus that invoking methods with arguments in EL is not a JSF 2.0 specific feature. It's an EL 2.2 specific feature. EL 2.2 is part of Java EE 6, which JSF 2.0 is also part of. So it *look like* a JSF 2.0 specific feature, but it isn't. JSF 2.0 is backwards compatible with Servlet 2.5 / EL 2.1 which lacks this feature. On the other hand, JSF 1.x is forwards compatible with Servlet 3.0 / EL 2.2, so it would also be possible to use this feature in JSF 1.x then, also using JBoss EL on Servlet 2.5 / EL 2.1.

Comment: Is it use for value method of `ui:repeate` with ajax request? Refer to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12884049/does-not-uirepeat-work-when-ajax-request

Answer (score 1):

BalusC's answer is correct, however, when you use maven, you should exclude el-api 1.0 transitive dependency like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.seam</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-el</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.GA</version>
    <!-- exclude el-api 1.0 transitive dependency -->
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```