# JSF2 Action parameter

Tags: jsf, action, jsf-2

I have read about passing parameters from jsf page to managedbean through actionListener. Is it also possible to pass a parameter to a simple action method?

Thank you for reading...

---

Thank you both for your advices! I would be lost without you :-)

Following worked for me:

```
<h:commandLink id="link" action="#{overviewController.showDetails}" >
   <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{overviewController.show_id}" value="#{project.id}" />
   <h:outputText value="#{project.title}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

So now who deserves the green tick? :-P can I give two of them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. Either:

```
action="#{bean.method(param)}"
```

Or

```
<h:commandButton .. >
    <f:setPropertyActionListener
         target="#{bean.targetProperty}" value="#{param}" />
</h:commandbutton>
```

(and use the bean property in the method)

Answer (score 13):

You're talking about parameters in this form?

```
<h:commandButton action="#{bean.action(param)}" />
```

That depends on the EL implementation. Only JBoss EL and JSP 2.2 EL is capable of doing this. How to install JBoss EL is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284236/jsf-2-0-method-invocation).

Alternatively, you can also just use `f:param`. The `f:param` used to work with `h:commandLink` only, but since JSF 2.0 it also works on `h:commandButton`. E.g.

```
<h:commandButton action="#{bean.action}">
    <f:param name="foo" value="bar" />
</h:commandButton>
```

with a `@ManagedProperty` which sets the parameter as managed bean property:

```
@ManagedProperty("#{param.foo}")
private String foo;
```

With this you're however limited to standard types (`String`, `Number`, `Boolean`). An alternative is the `f:setPropertyActionListener`:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{bean.action}">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bean.foo}" value="#{otherBean.complexObject}" />
</h:commandButton>
```

That said, there are more ways as well, but this all depends on the sole functional requirement and the bean scopes. Probably you don't need to pass a "parameter" at all after all.

Answer (score 3):

The new spec. JSF2 allows that the action method receives a param so you be able to do

```
<h:commandButton action="#{bean.action(otherBean.complexObject)}">
```

at the ManagedBean the method will be:

```
public String action(Object complexObject)
```

**Note: make sure you include the “el-impl-2.2.jar” **

Comment: This is not JSF specific. This is EL specific and part of Servlet 3.0 / JSP 2.2 (Tomcat 7, Glassfish 3, JBoss AS 6, etc). So when you run JSF 2.0 on Servlet 2.5, it won't work. This is regardless of the JSF version.