# Getting a GET request param into an @ViewScoped bean

Tags: java, jsf-2, javabeans, cdi, scopes

I have a (request-scoped) list from which the user may select a "PQ" (list of links). When clicked or otherwise entered into the browser the main page for each PQ shall be displayed. Each PQ's page is of the form

`http://localhost:8080/projectname/main.jsf?id=2`

Here's the PQ bean first:

```java
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class PqHome implements Serializable
{
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="...")
    private EntityManager em;

    private Integer id;
    private PQ instance;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
        System.out.println("ID is " + id); // ID from URL param

        instance = em.find(PQ.class, id);       
    }

    public Integer getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public PQ getInstance()
    {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Here's the main.xhtml:

```html
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                ...>
  <ui:define name="metadata">
    <f:metadata>
      <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{pqHome.id}">
        <f:convertNumber integerOnly="#{true}" />
      </f:viewParam>
      <!--f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{pqHome.init}" /-->
    </f:metadata>
  </ui:define>
  <ui:define name="title">
    <h:outputText value="Main" />
  </ui:define>
  ...
</ui:composition>
```

Any time I select or otherwise refresh the page/URL I get a `NullPointerException` from the `EntityManager`:

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: WELD-000049 Unable to invoke [method] @PostConstruct public de.mycomp.myproj.beans.PqHome.init() on de.mycomp.myproj.beans.PqHome@4f0ea68f
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractClassBean.defaultPostConstruct(AbstractClassBean.java:595)
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: id to load is required for loading
at org.hibernate.event.spi.LoadEvent.<init>(LoadEvent.java:87)
at org.hibernate.event.spi.LoadEvent.<init>(LoadEvent.java:59)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:961)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:957)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:787)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:762)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.find(AbstractEntityManager.java:221)
at de.mycomp.myproj.beans.PqHome.init(PqHome.java:47)
... 56 more
```

[Line 47 is em.find(...)]

The line

```
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{pqHome.init}" />
```

doesn't make things any better. I'm pretty desparate now.

How do you get URL GET request params into an `@ViewScoped` bean?

**Note**:  I bet it's not a trivial thing to do. Chances are I'm doing something wrong here conceptually, so any tips on how to improve are welcome. I felt that I needed to choose `@ViewScoped` because there will be more complex AJAX-based GUI on that page which I'd really like to keep accessible via URL GET params.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `@PostConstruct` is invoked *directly* after bean's construction and all dependency injection (such as `@PersistenceContext`, `@EJB`, `@ManagedProperty`, `@Inject`, etc..etc..).

The `<f:viewParam>` sets its value during the update model values phase, which is far after (post)construction of the bean. So inside the `@PostConstruct` the `<f:viewParam>` value is simply not yet been set. It'll be still `null` at that point.

You're close with `<f:event type="preRenderView">`, but you have to **remove** the `@PostConstruct` annotation.

So:

```html
<f:viewParam name="pq" value="#{pqHome.id}">
    <f:convertNumber integerOnly="#{true}" />
</f:viewParam>
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{pqHome.init}" />
```

with

```
private Integer id;

public void init() {
    instance = em.find(PQ.class, id);       
}
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, I'd suggest to use a `Converter` for this instead. See also [Communication in JSF 2.0](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html) - [Converting and validating GET request parameters](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ConvertingAndValidatingGETRequestParameters).

Also the combination `@Named @ViewScoped` won't work as intended. The JSF-specific `@ViewScoped` works in combination with JSF-specific `@ManagedBean` only. Your CDI-specific `@Named` will behave like `@RequestScoped` this way. Either use `@ManagedBean` instead of `@Named` or use CDI-specific `@ConversationScoped` instead of `@ViewScoped`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I had found out that `@PostConstruct` comes far before f:event, see the answer by Gaim in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988899/trying-to-use-view-parameters-in-postconstruct. I'm still missing sources/books that would explicitly state such things. The problem for me as a Java EE 6 newcomer is to grasp the scopes and what CDI `@Named` would gain over JSF `@ManagedBean`, also given that almost any RichFaces sources use the `@ManagedBean @ViewScoped` combination. I just tried out CDI, probably dumping it now. I don't see the gain for me (yet).

Comment: You may find the linked "Communication in JSF 2.0" article useful to have a good "JSF 2.0 in a nutshell" overview.

Comment: Oh yeah this is great stuff, I really missed that one. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

There is a better way to get id from url. Just use it in @PostConstruct init() method to get "id" from url:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("id");
```

You can still use ViewScoped and @PostConstruct.