# JSF view-param only works from same page

Tags: jsf-2

Probably I am missing something here.

I have a template with a menu, with the options passign parameters to the JSF page:

```
<rich:menuItem label="Todos" action="#{mainMenuCtrl.listTickets}">
  <f:param name="baseLocation" value=""/>
  <f:param name="ticketStatus" value="Solicitado"/>
</rich:menuItem>
<rich:menuItem label="H. General" action="#{mainMenuCtrl.listTickets}">
  <f:param name="baseLocation" value="HGN"/>
  <f:param name="ticketStatus" value="Solicitado"/>
</rich:menuItem>
```

The controller just redirects to the page:

```
public String listTickets() {
  return "ticketsList.xhtml?faces-redirect=true&includeViewParams=true";
}
```

And ticketsList.xhtml has the `metadata` section:

```
<f:metadata>
  <f:viewParam name="baseLocation" value="#{ticketsListCtrl.baseLocation}" converter="es.caib.gesma.gesman.data.converter.LocationConverterByShortCode"/>
  <f:viewParam name="ticketStatus" value="#{ticketsListCtrl.ticketStatus}" converter="es.caib.gesma.gesman.data.converter.TicketStatusConverter"/>
  <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{ticketsListCtrl.retrieveTickets()}" />  
</f:metadata>
```

The problem is that, when I am at another page (`index.xhtml`) that uses the same template, clicking in any of the menu items drives me `ticketsList.xhtml` but both params are empty.

```
../ticketsList.xhtml?baseLocation=&ticketStatus=
```

When I click the same item from `ticketsList.xhtml`, it shows the correct URL and from there anything works ok.

```
../ticketsList.xhtml?baseLocation=HGN&ticketStatus=Solicitado
```

Can anyone point to me why are the view-params missing when clicking from other pages?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `includeViewParams` will include the view parameters of the **current** view, not of the target view.

You basically need to define the to-be-included view parameters as `<f:viewParam>` in `index.xhtml` as well, or to look for an alternate approach.

Comment: There are several pages (and many more to come), and from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344056/jsf2-how-achieve-site-wide-viewparam-handling-policy-using-a-template it seems I cannot put it in the template. The only option left is the `ManagedProperty`?

Comment: That's the best alternative left, yes. Best would be to design a separate/distinct request scoped bean for this.

Comment: The "separate/distinct request scoped bean" means a bean only for the two parameters, to be used by the bean of the receiving page? Otherwise I don't understand it.