# NPE in @ManagedBean - javax.servlet.ServletException: An error occurred performing resource injection

Tags: spring, jsf, primefaces, managed-bean

I have Spring project, now I want to add few JSF (Primefaces) xhtml pages, but I get null pointer exception in my @ManagedBean on @PostConstruct method when i try get data from existing services?

Do You know how to properly import AuctionViewService to my @ManagedBean? I think that's the problem but I dont know how to fix it :)

Below java classes there's my stacktrace with null pointer (also i mark line with NPE in SalesBean.java)

This is my xhtml page:

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/main.css"></link>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" type=""></script>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/bootstrap.min.js" type=""></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/common/main.js"></script>

    <title>Sales</title>

</h:head>
<h:body>
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="navigationMenuPlaceholder"></div>

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div id="page-content-wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                        <h:outputText value="#{SalesBean.firstName}"/>
                        <h:outputText value="#{SalesBean.lastName}" />
                    </p:panelGrid>

                    <p:dataTable var="property" value="#{SalesBean.userProperty}">
                        <p:column headerText="PropertyId">
                            <h:outputText value="#{property.propertyId}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="UserId">
                            <h:outputText value="#{property.userId}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Street">
                            <h:outputText value="#{property.street}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="House no">
                            <h:outputText value="#{property.homeNumber}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Local no">
                            <h:outputText value="#{property.localNumber}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Post code">
                            <h:outputText value="#{property.postCode}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="City">
                            <h:outputText value="#{property.city}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Price">
                            <h:outputText value="#{property.price}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Size">
                            <h:outputText value="#{property.size}" />
                        </p:column>

                    </p:dataTable>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footerPlaceholder">
    </div>
    <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->

</div>
</h:body>
</html>
```

SalesBean:

```html
package application.beans;

import application.model.views.AuctionView;
import application.service.AuctionViewService;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Setter
@Getter
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean(name="SalesBean")
public class SalesBean {

    @ManagedProperty("#{auctionViewService}")
    private AuctionViewService auctionViewService;

    //private String userName =  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
    private String userName =  "seller@seller.com";
    private String firstName = "first";
    private String lastName = "last";
    private List<AuctionView> userProperty = new ArrayList<>();

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() { userProperty = auctionViewService.findByEmail(userName); //NULL POINTER EXCEPTION in this line
    }
}
```

AuctionViewServiceImpl:

```html
package application.service;

import application.dao.*;
import application.model.views.AuctionView;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import java.util.List;

@Service("auctionViewService")
public class AuctionViewServiceImpl implements AuctionViewService {

    final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(AuctionViewServiceImpl.class.getName());
    private final AuctionViewDAO auctionViewDAO;

    public AuctionViewServiceImpl(AuctionViewDAO auctionViewDAO) {
        this.auctionViewDAO = auctionViewDAO;
    }

    @Override
    public List<AuctionView> findAll() {
        return auctionViewDAO.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<Object> findByType(String propertyType) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(auctionViewDAO.findByType(propertyType), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @Override
    public List<AuctionView> findByEmail(String email) {
        return auctionViewDAO.findByEmail(email);
    }
}
```

faces-config.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd"
              version="2.1">

    <application>
        <el-resolver>
            org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
        </el-resolver>
    </application>

</faces-config>
```

web.xml

```html
<web-app  version="2.4"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>khn</display-name>


    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>WEB-INF/servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

stacktrace: https://pastebin.com/iaBHUupQ
If needed i can attach more files and whole project structure, but problem is in importing AuctionViewService to SalesBean, or maybe in mixing JSF and Spring annotations

Comment: Have you tried with @Autowired, instead of @ManagedProperty?

Comment: I tried this approach before posting, but still null pointer on same line

Comment: Stacktraces inline please... A stacktrance (other then maybe a stackoverflow one) can never be that long

Comment: And java webapp 2.4? And wehere and what is the error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring JSF integration: how to inject a Spring component/service in JSF managed bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18387993/spring-jsf-integration-how-to-inject-a-spring-component-service-in-jsf-managed)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I changed @ManagedBean annotation to @Component, link AuctionViewService with @Autowire, and it works for me :) but how can I explain this situation?

```html
package application.beans;

import application.model.views.AuctionView;
import application.service.AuctionViewService;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Setter
@Getter
@ViewScoped
@Component
//@ManagedBean(name="SalesBean")
public class SalesBean implements Serializable {

    @Autowired
    private  AuctionViewService auctionViewService;

    //private String userName =  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
    private String userName =  "seller@seller.com";
    private String firstName = "first";
    private String lastName = "last";
    private List<AuctionView> userProperty = new ArrayList<>();


    @PostConstruct
    public void init() { userProperty = auctionViewService.findByEmail(userName);
    }
}
```

Comment: `@Component` make the `@Autowired` be scanned and then works ([Spring docs](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_autowired_annotation.htm)), for `@ManagedProperty` check some question, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579711/managedpropertyvalue-param-id-in-a-non-request-scope-bean) for more info

Comment: @WoAiNii: check this duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18387993/spring-jsf-integration-how-to-inject-a-spring-component-service-in-jsf-managed (and vote for it as duplicate)