# How can we do 'Like' system in Jsf on a Blog Project?

Tags: java, jsf, button

I'm doing blog system in JSF. I have an idea similar to Facebook's 'like' system. I want to do my own such system in this blog. I ran into a problem because of  tag. I mean, the page is refreshing when user clicked the like button. How can I fix that? Here is my JSF code:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{blogPost.queryPosts}" var="post">
    <div style="border:1px;border-color: #333;" >
        <li><h1>#{post.title}</h1></li>
        <li><h:outputText value="#{post.content}" escape="false" /> </li>
        <li>Like :<h:button value="Like" onclick="#{likePost.like2Post(post.id)}" title="Like" />
        </li>
        <li>reBlog</li>
        <li>Comments:</li>
    </div>
</ui:repeat>
```

Comment: I'm not experienced with JSF, but to accomplish what you want you need a button that will call likePost.like2post method via Ajax.

Comment: I tried it before but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

The onclick attribute on the button is a DHTML event attribute to call client side javascript. If you need to do a form submit. Use like this:

```
<h:commandButton value="Like" action="#{likePost.like2Post(post.id)}" />
```

And to pass a parameter, you need to have el-api-2.2.jar and el-impl-2.2.jar. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599948/jsf2-action-parameter) for more alternatives.

Moreover

```
<h:button>
```

is used for GET requests.

```
<h:commandButton> and <h:commandLink> are used to generate POST requests.
```