# Is there a way to pass an argument to a method from a JSF page?

Tags: jsf, el

I'm using JSF 2.  Is it possible to send an argument to a method from a JSF page?  I want to do something like this:

```
<p:dataTable id="groupsTable" var="group" 
   value="#{groupHandler.groupsByUserId( userHandler.selectedUser.id )}" >
   //...
</p:dataTable>
```

Thanks,
rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, it is possible to send an argument to a method in JSF page. Your above code will work if method `groupsByUserId()` method inside bean `groupHandler` has this format

```
  public List<Group> groupsByUserId(Long id){
       List<Group> group = myEJB.findGroupsByUserId(id);
       return group;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not specific to [JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info). This is specific to [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info). If you're running on a Servlet 3.0 / EL 2.2 capable container (Glassfish 3, JBossAS 6, Tomcat 7, etc) and your `web.xml` is declared conform the Servlet 3.0 spec, then your code will work.

On anything else, it won't work. You would need to upgrade to a Servlet 3.0 / EL 2.2 capable container, or to alter your `web.xml` declaration (it would however make your webapp incompatible with Servlet 2.5 containers or older), or to install a custom EL implementation which supports that, such as [JBoss EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284236/jsf-2-0-method-invocation/3284328#3284328).

Once again, this is regardless of the JSF version used! It was just the coincidence that EL 2.2 was introduced in Java EE 6 which also comes together with JSF 2.0. So there's some kind of urban myth/impression that it came along with JSF 2.0.

Comment: Thanks BalusC, very helpful as always!  I'm sure I tried something like this a couple years ago and couldn't get it to work, I think you just explained why.  Harry Pham's solution worked fine because I'm on GlassFish.  Thanks!

Comment: BalusC, does JBoss EL faster than EL2.2? I heard that JUEL much faster than EL2.2 that come with GF, have u try JUEL before?

Comment: @Harry: sorry, I have not ever measured/read about EL performance, so I wouldn't be able to objectively answer this.