# JSF: Bean method call with parameter

Tags: jsf, parameters, el, javabeans

I can't get method calls with parameters to work in JSF 2.0 (MyFaces) and Tomcat 6.

This is how I try it:

`<f:selectItems var="item" value="#{bla.someList}
itemValue="#{item.value1}"
itemLabel="#{item.value2}">
   <f:param name="param1" value="0" />
</f:selectItems>`

I can't define the method like this, right? And why not?

```
getSomeList(int a)
```

So this is what I tried:

```
getSomeList() {
Integer a = Integer.parseInt(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("param1")); 
return doSomething(a);
}
```

And this is what I get:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:417)
```

I would be very grateful if someone helped me out. Thanks!

UPDATE: Ah, it worked with #{bla.getSomeList(0)}!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *I can't define the method like this, right?*
>
> ```
> getSomeList(int a)
> ```

No.

> *And why not?*

Because you're using old Tomcat 6 which doesn't support EL 2.2 where this feature was introduced.

> *And this is what I get:*
>
> ```
> java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
> java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:417)
> ```

Because there it is `null`. The `<f:param>` works in links/buttons only, not on plain components.

In order to get method calls in EL to work, you need to upgrade to a Servlet 3.0 / EL 2.2 capable container like Tomcat 7, or to replace Tomcat 6's default EL 2.1  implementation by one which supports parameterized method calls. For detail see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284236/jsf-2-0-method-invocation/3284328#3284328). Once done that, you can use

```
<f:selectItems value="#{bla.getSomeList(0)}" ... />
```

An alternative is to replace `List` by `Map`, which can be a custom implementation which does (lazy) loading on `get()` method.

```
public Map<String, List<Something>> getSomeMap() {
    return someCustomLazyLoadingMap;
}
```

with

```
<f:selectItems value="#{bla.someMap.keyName}" ... />
```

Comment: Thanks! But it worked with #{bla.getSomeList(0)} instead of #{bla.someList(0)}

Answer (score 0):

Try using

`<f:selectItems var="item" value="#{bla.someList(0)} itemValue="#{item.value1}" itemLabel="#{item.value2}"/>`

This works for some implementations of JSF.

Comment: This is not JSF specific. This is EL specific.

Comment: Yes you are right. But I knew it was possible in some cases :)