# jsf 2 method parameters action listener

Tags: methods, jsf-2, parameter-passing, el

Is there a way to pass a variable into a method param:

```
 <h:commandButton value="Add to Order" 
 actionListener="#{orderBasket.addItems(currentItem.id)}"/>
```

This always seems to pass 0 into the method for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's only possible when you use [`action` instead of `actionListener`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener/3909382#3909382)

```
<h:commandButton value="Add to Order" 
    action="#{orderBasket.addItems(currentItem.id)}"/>
```

**and** you're running a Servlet 3.0 / EL 2.2 capable container (Tomcat 7, Glassfish 3, JBoss 6, etc) **and** your `web.xml` is declared conform Servlet 3.0 spec with the following root declaration

```
<web-app
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
```

If the latter two are not true for your case (e.g. you're using Servlet 2.5), then you need to replace the EL implementation by another one which supports that, such as JBoss EL. For detail, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284236/jsf-2-0-method-invocation/3284328#3284328).

Comment: hhmm...just upgraded to jetty 8...changed the web-xml and still having the same issue..using glassfish el-impl.

Comment: I have this in my faces-config...<el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>...Will that be a problem?

Comment: ahh.the problem was I was retrieving currentItem from the URL and when I submitted this was getting wiped..will raise a separate question