# Trigger a commandButton action with variable passed by javascript in JSF

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsf, primefaces

I am trying to make an `Ajax` call from my .`xhtml` page to my backing `ManagedBean` function as shown below:

**.xhtml form code**

```
            <h:form id = "jsfform">
                <h:commandButton id="button" action="#{cellBean.children()}">
                    <f:ajax render=":results" />
                </h:commandButton> </h:form>
            <h:panelGroup id="results">
                <th>Child cells</th>
                <td>
                <ui:repeat value="#{cellBean.childCells}" var="cell">
                        <tr>#{cell.cellName}</tr>
                </ui:repeat>
                </td>
            </h:panelGroup>
```

**managed bean's function code**

```
 public List<Cell> children(){
    this.childCells.add(new Cell("cell1"));
    return this.childCells;
}
```

The above code works fine since each and every time i trigger the commandButton, a new "`Cell`" object is added into the list and rendered asynchronously in my form.

I trigger the `commandButton` from javascript using the tricky way (which is does not seem to me the best option)

```
document.getElementById('jsfform:button').onclick();
```

**What I want to achieve now** is do something similar but with `cellBean.children` function having parameters (f.e a list of Strings), pass it to the backing bean function and do stuff, what should I do? Obviously I cannot trigger the commandButton as I did previously because I cannot pass parameters like that

Example:

```
        <h:form id = "jsfform">
            <h:commandButton id="button" action="#{cellBean.children(a_list)}">
                <f:ajax render=":results" />
            </h:commandButton> </h:form>
        <h:panelGroup id="results">
            <th>Child cells</th>
            <td>
            <ui:repeat value="#{cellBean.childCells}" var="cell">
                    <tr>#{cell.cellName}</tr>
            </ui:repeat>
            </td>
        </h:panelGroup>


public List<Cell> children(List<String> alist){
    this.childCells.add(new Cell("cell1"));
    return this.childCells;
}
```

Thanks In advance.

=============== **UPDATE** ==================

Following this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28591301/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-as-parameters-to-jsf-action-method) what I have tried so far is:

**.xhtml form**

```
 <h:form id = "jsfform">
                <h:inputHidden id="childCells" value="#{cellBean.childCellsStr}" />
                <h:inputHidden id="parentCells" value="#{cellBean.parentCellsStr}" />
                <h:commandButton id="button"  style="display: none" action="#{cellBean.children()}">
                    <f:actionListener binding="#{cellBean.checkBtnDisable()}" /> 
                    <f:ajax render=":ajaxform"/>
                </h:commandButton>
```

**Javascript code**

```
  // json1 && json2 are two json strings
document.getElementById('jsfform:childCells').value = json1;
document.getElementById('jsfform:parentCells').value = json2;
//trigger the button of the form with javascript
document.getElementById('jsfform:button').onclick();
```

**Managed Bean**

```
private String childCellsStr;
private String parentCellsStr;
//getters && setters
```

Unfortunately, even the values of the `inputHidden` fields are set, the **backing bean setters are not triggered and the values are null**

Comment: Did you try something? Where should the parameter content com from? Possibly these QAs help: [Passing parameter to JSF action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401771/passing-parameter-to-jsf-action) or [How to pass JavaScript variables as parameters to JSF action method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28591301/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-as-parameters-to-jsf-action-method)

Comment: The parameter content is already in a javascript variable, resources seem very helpful, will have a look at them thanks

Comment: Hi @Selaron , I have followed the example you provided me with in the comments section but is not working as expected, could you please check my updated question?

Comment: And the action method IS called? Did ypu debug the http request? Are the values there? What if you (for testing) make then none-hidden?

Comment: @Kukeltje Yes the action method is called. I debugged the http request and I see the code calling the `getChildCellsStr()` and `getParentCellsStr()` getters but the values are null, the code does not go to the setters of the variables. I made the fields visible (h:inputText) and when the javascript function is called I see the value set into them, but the behaviour still remains the same :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not set/updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandbutton-commandlink-ajax-action-listener-method-not-invoked-or-input-value) #9 in there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do is add the `execute` parameter in the tag (following [this tutorial](https://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-ajax-hello-world-example/)).
Now the setters are called and the backing beans take the values I want

**.xhtml code**

```
<h:form id = "jsfform">
                <h:inputHidden id="childCells" value="#{cellBean.childCellsStr}" />
                <h:inputHidden id="parentCells" value="#{cellBean.parentCellsStr}" />
                <h:commandButton id="button"  style="display: none" action="#{cellBean.children()}">
                    <f:actionListener binding="#{cellBean.checkBtnDisable()}" /> <!--first call the children function, then call the checkBtnDisable -->
                    <f:ajax execute="childCells parentCells" render=":ajaxform"/>
                </h:commandButton>
            </h:form>
```

**Javascript code**

```
    document.getElementById('jsfform:childCells').value = json1;
document.getElementById('jsfform:parentCells').value = json2;
//trigger the button of the form with javascript
document.getElementById('jsfform:button').onclick();
```

**Java Bean**

```
private String childCellsStr;
private String parentCellsStr;
//getters && setters
```

Comment: So #9 in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandbutton-commandlink-ajax-action-listener-method-not-invoked-or-input-value

Comment: Thank you @Kukeltje for your responses, your post seems very helpful :)

Comment: All >15 upvoted Q or A in jsf are helpful. Search for them (sort on votes) and read them and remember their existence. Most 'issues' you can encounter with jsf have been asked and answered since it is a mature technology