# How to reference Java Collection entry from JSF 2 ManagedProperty?

Tags: jsf, dependency-injection, jsf-2, managed-bean

I have an application that has a bean that holds a list of Contacts which are referenced from various domain objects throughout the application:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class ContactHolder implements Serializable {
    private ArrayList<Contact> contactsList;
    //getters and setters...
}
```

Contacts can be created and added to `contactsList` from various JSF pages and entries in this list need to be referenced as a ManagedProperty in various domain objects throughout the application. For instance, look at some of my domain objects:

```
@ManagedBean
public class Claim implements Serializable {
    private Contact insured; //needs to reference entry in contactsList
}

@ManagedBean
public class Vehicle implements Serializable {
    private Contact driver; //needs to reference entry in contactsList
}
```

Because users will have the choice to select from an existing Contact or creating a new one for each domain object, the same Contact entry in `contactsList` could be referenced from more than one domain object. Is there a way to reference/inject a specific Java Collection entry as a ManagedProperty in JSF 2? Or is there a better approach to handling this scenario?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, I see ways wherein you remember and pass list indexes around, but this will end up to be pretty clumsy.

Much better, if you're targeting a Servlet 3.0 / EL 2.2 capable container (Tomcat 7, Glassfish 3, etc) wherein invoking methods with additional arguments is supported, or can install [JBoss EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284236/jsf-2-0-method-invocation/3284328#3284328) which adds the same enhancement for EL 2.1, then you should be able to just pass that object as action method argument.

E.g.

```
<h:dataTable value="#{contactHolder.contacts}" var="contact">
    <h:column>
        <h:commandButton value="Claim" action="#{claim.doAction(contact)}" />
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

with in `Claim` managed bean:

```
public void doAction(Contact contact) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response!