# weblogic10.3 JSF2 built in jars

Tags: jsf-2, weblogic-10.x

In our application ,we are using JSF2 with weblogin10.3.4,

The weblogic10.3.4 comes with JSF 2.0 ..We deployed JSF2.0 as library in weblogic.

But when we deploy the jsf application,weblogic reports the ClassNotFound for JSF specific classes.

Any one has tried this before...

Thanks
Vijay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a weblogic-application.xml like below. This forces to load classes under application library instead of weblogic jars.

WebContent->META-INF->weblogic-application.xml

```
<weblogic-application xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <prefer-application-packages>
        <package-name>javax.faces.*</package-name>
        <package-name>com.sun.faces.*</package-name>
    </prefer-application-packages>
</weblogic-application>
```

And if you want to use EL2.2 you will need to add el 2.2 jars to setDomainEnv file where it is located at "bea11\user_projects\domains\base_domain\bin"

Add the following line:

set PATCH_CLASSPATH=D:\dev\lib\el-impl-2.2.jar;D:\dev\lib\el-api-2.2.jar;

edited file looks like below:

```
if "%PRODUCTION_MODE%"=="true" (
    set debugFlag=false
    set testConsoleFlag=false
    set iterativeDevFlag=false
    set logErrorsToConsoleFlag=false
)

    @REM If you want to override the default Patch Classpath, Library Path and Path for this domain,
    @REM Please uncomment the following lines and add a valid value for the environment variables
    @REM set PATCH_CLASSPATH=[myPatchClasspath] (windows)
    @REM set PATCH_LIBPATH=[myPatchLibpath] (windows)
    @REM set PATCH_PATH=[myPatchPath] (windows)
    @REM PATCH_CLASSPATH=[myPatchClasspath] (unix)
    @REM PATCH_LIBPATH=[myPatchLibpath] (unix)
    @REM PATCH_PATH=[myPatchPath] (unix)

    set PATCH_CLASSPATH=D:\dev\lib\el-impl-2.2.jar;D:\dev\lib\el-api-2.2.jar;

    call "%WL_HOME%\common\bin\commEnv.cmd"

    set WLS_HOME=%WL_HOME%\server
```

Good luck

Comment: Hi...with your solution my web app doesn't have jsf jars ,it should pick it from web logic

Answer (score 0):

Adding the below in web-inf/weblogic.xml solves the issue

```
<wls:weblogic-version>10.3.4</wls:weblogic-version>

    <wls:context-root>/</wls:context-root>

<wls:library-ref>
    <wls:library-name>jsf</wls:library-name>
<wls:specification-version>2.0</wls:specification-version>
<wls:implementation-version>1.0.0.0_2-0-2</wls:implementation-version>
    <wls:exact-match>true</wls:exact-match>
    </wls:library-ref>
```