# How to pass a method argument to getter?

Tags: jsf, parameters, el

I want to use a datalist

```
<rich:dataList value="#{bean.itemsOnLevel}" var="item">
   <h:outputText value="#{item.value}" />
</rich:dataList>
```

but my getter needs a parameter

```
public List getItemsOnLevel(int level);
```

how can I pass the level?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're already targeting a Servlet 3.0 compatible container (Tomcat 7, Glassfish 3, JBoss 6, etc) with a Servlet 3.0 compatible `web.xml` in your webapp, then you can make use of the new EL 2.2 feature of invoking methods with arguments:

```
<rich:dataList value="#{bean.getItemsOnLevel(1)}" var="item">
   <h:outputText value="#{item.value}" />
</rich:dataList>
```

If you're however targeting an older Servlet 2.5 compatible container (Tomcat 6, Glassfish 2, JBoss 4/5, etc), then your best bet is to install JBoss EL to achieve the same. See also this answer for details: [Invoke direct methods or methods with arguments / variables / parameters in EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284236/jsf-2-0-method-invocation/3284328#3284328)