# How to display elements of ArrayList by index in EL expression in JSF page

Tags: jsf, arraylist, el

I want to display java arraylist into JSF page. I generated arraylist from database. Now I want to display the list into JSF page by calling the list elements index by index number. Is it possible to pass a parameter to bean method from an EL expression in JSF page directly and display it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can access a list element by a specific index using the brace notation `[]`.

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Bean {

    private List<String> list;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        list = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three");
    }

    public List<String> getList() {
        return list;
    }

}
```

```
#{bean.list[0]}
<br />
#{bean.list[1]}
<br />
#{bean.list[2]}
```

As to parameter passing, surely it's possible. EL 2.2 (or JBoss EL when you're still on EL 2.1) supports calling bean methods with arguments.

```
#{bean.doSomething(foo, bar)}
```

#### See also:

- [Our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)
- [Invoke direct methods or methods with arguments / variables / parameters in EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284236/invoke-direct-methods-or-methods-with-arguments-variables-parameters-in-el)

---

I however wonder if it isn't easier to just use a component which iterates over all elements of the list, such as `<ui:repeat>` or `<h:dataTable>`,  so that you don't need to know the size beforehand nor to get every individual item by index. E.g.

```html
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.list}" var="item">
    #{item}<br/>
</ui:repeat>
```

or

```html
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.list}" var="item">
    <h:column>#{item}</h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

#### See also:

- [How iterate over List<T> and render each item in JSF Facelets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20098626/how-iterate-over-listt-and-render-each-item-in-jsf-facelets)