# How iterate over List<T> and render each item in JSF Facelets

Tags: list, jsf, facelets, data-presentation

I am wondering how to display a `List<T>` as obtained below in a Facelet:

```
public List<T> searchByString(String string) {
    return getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("Userdetails.findByUsername").setParameter("username", "%" + string + "%").getResultList();
}
```

Would a `<h:dataTable>` be a suitable way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're going need to iterate over it. JSF 2 offers three iteration components out the box. Provided that the `User` entity look like below,

```
@Entity
public class User {
    private @Id Long id;
    private String username;
    private String email;
    private LocalDate birthdate;
    // Add/generate getters+setters.
}
```

and that the search results are assigned as a `List<User> users` property of a bean which is available as `#{bean}`,

```
@Named @RequestScoped
public class Bean {
    private List<User> users;
    // Add/generate postconstruct+getter.
}
```

here are some examples based on it:

1. [`<h:dataTable>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/dataTable.html), an UI component which generates a HTML `<table>`.

   ```
   <h:dataTable value="#{bean.users}" var="user">
       <h:column>#{user.id}</h:column>
       <h:column>#{user.username}</h:column>
       <h:column><a href="mailto:#{user.email}">#{user.email}</a></h:column>
       <h:column>#{user.birthdate}</h:column>
   </h:dataTable>
   ```
2. [`<ui:repeat>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/ui/repeat.html), an UI component which generates no HTML markup (so, you'd have to write all that HTML in the desired fashion yourself, which could easily be changed to e.g. `<ul><li>`, or `<dl><dt><dd>`, or `<div><span>`, etc):

   ```
   <table>
       <ui:repeat value="#{bean.users}" var="user">
           <tr>
               <td>#{user.id}</td>
               <td>#{user.username}</td>
               <td><a href="mailto:#{user.email}">#{user.email}</a></td>
               <td>#{user.birthdate}</td>
           </td>
       </ui:repeat>
   </table>
   ```
3. [`<c:forEach>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/c/forEach.html), a tag handler which runs during view build time instead of view render time (background explanation here: [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)), it also doesn't produce any HTML markup:

   ```
   <table>
       <c:forEach items="#{bean.users}" var="user">
           <tr>
               <td>#{user.id}</td>
               <td>#{user.username}</td>
               <td><a href="mailto:#{user.email}">#{user.email}</a></td>
               <td>#{user.birthdate}</td>
           </td>
       </c:forEach>
   </table>
   ```

#### See also:

- [Java EE 6 tutorial - Adding components to a page - using `<h:dataTable>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnarf.html#bnarz)
- [How and when should I load the model from database for h:dataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765853/when-should-i-load-the-collection-from-database-for-hdatatable)

Answer (score 1):

You can save your List in a class variable, give it a getter and (maybe) a setter. Declare `searchByString` method as `void` and call it with let's say a (provided you are using PrimeFaces):

```
<p:commandLink update="@form" process="@this" action="#{myBean.searchByString}">
```

myBean:

```
public void searchByString(String string) {     
    userList = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("Userdetails.findByUsername").setParameter("username", "%" + string + "%").getResultList();
}
```

provided your table sits in a form that you just updated you could display the `List` in it.

```
 <p:dataTable var="user" value="#{myBean.userList}">  
    <p:column headerText="Name">  
        <h:outputText value="#{user.name}" />  
    </p:column>  
 </p:dataTable>
```