# For JSF 2.0, How to Enable EL 2.2 on Tomcat 6

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat, netbeans, el

i use netbean 6.9.1 with apache tomcat 6.in my jsf page, i want call method with parameter, for current, i use tomcat 6 with EL default.

i downloaded EL 2.2 from 
http://download.java.net/maven/glassfish/javax/el/el-api/2.2.0-SNAPSHOT/el-api-2.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

http://download.java.net/maven/glassfish/org/glassfish/web/el-impl/2.2.0-SNAPSHOT/el-impl-2.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

i renamed these files to el-api-2.2.0.jar and el-impl-2.2.0.jar, then i copy to tomcat lib (C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 6.0.26\lib)

In the web.xml, i added this

```
  <context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

KategoriManager.java (for testing)

```
public String editSetup(Integer id) {
    return "kategori_edit";
}
```

and Edit.jsp

```
---cut---
<h:commandLink value="Edit" action="#{kategoriManager.editSetup(1)}"/>
---cut---
```

but in IDE netbean, i still got tooltip error like **"the function must be used with prefix"**

i run this web, but i got error

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Status report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
Apache Tomcat/6.0.26
```

how to enable EL 2.2 on Tomcat 6 ? please help..

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The JARs should be placed in webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib`, not in server's `/lib`. You should also make absolutely sure that you don't have another copy of EL API JAR in `/WEB-INF/lib`. Most starters drop for some unobvious reason for example `javaee.jar` in `/WEB-INF/lib` to "fix" compilation errors.

An alternative is to use JBoss EL. See also [Invoke direct methods or methods with arguments / variables / parameters in EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284236/jsf-2-0-method-invocation/3284328#3284328) for instructions.

Comment: but i got tutorial from [link]http://wiki.apache.org/myfaces/HowToEnableEl22 that jar file copied to server's lib.anyway, where the `code`/WEB-INF/lib ? in netbean, i go to this folder, but just can find two files `code` faces-config.xml and web.xml.im sorry, i'm newbie in java

Comment: i removed el-api and change to jboss-el, i downloaded from http://www.springsource.com/repository/app/bundle/version/detail?name=com.springsource.org.jboss.el&version=2.0.0.GA&searchType=bundlesByName&searchQuery=expression but i got same error

Comment: I have no idea how Netbeans works, I have never really used it, but to the point you need to make sure that the JAR ends up in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder of the deployed webapp. This folder is part of standard servlet API and any self-respected IDE like Eclipse and IntelliJ just show it in the project structure. Perhaps Netbeans is hiding or abstracting it away. Consult the Netbeans manual for details.

Comment: thx for reply, now i use jboss-el, but i got exceptions org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /kategori/List.jsp(45,24) The function editSetup must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified.thank you

Comment: That just means that the environment is still not EL 2.2 enabled. In other words, the JAR file(s) are not at the right place (or still in server's `/lib`).