# EL function not found error

Tags: java, jsf-2, el

I am trying to call method using custom EL function with perameter of jsfbean.

```
<c:set var="test1" value="${cx:methodName('para')}" scope="session"/>
        <h:outputText value="#{test1}"/>
```

i made following id TLD and putted it into WEB-INF

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <taglib 
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd"
        version="2.1">

        <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
        <short-name>Custom_Functions</short-name>
        <uri>http://example.com/functions</uri>

        <function>
            <name>methodName</name>
            <function-class>funcionclass(Jsfbean)</function-class>
            <function-signature>java.lang.String methodName(java.lang.String)</function-signature>
        </function>
    </taglib>
```

i also configure in web.xml

```
<jsp-config> 
        <taglib> 
               <taglib-uri>http://example.com/functions</taglib-uri> 
               <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/functions.tld</taglib-location> 
        </taglib> 
</jsp-config>
```

and still it is getting Function not found error.

following is method code

```
public static String methodName(String s1) throws Exception
    {
        return "Kshitij";
    }
```

can any body help.

Comment: Are you using JSP or Facelets? You've created a JSP EL function, but your JSF 2.0 tag indicates that you're possibly actually using Facelets. Further, which servletcontainer are you targeting? Is it Servlet 3.0 compatible? Is the `web.xml` declared conform Servlet 3.0?

Comment: yes. i am using facelets. and this is my web.xml<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
      version="2.4">

Comment: Huh? Are you running JSF 2.0 on a Servlet 2.4 container? This ain't ever going to work without hacks. What exactly is your server make/version?

Comment: That's a Servlet 2.5 compatible container. You should set web.xml to Servlet 2.5.

Comment: i am getting error. like Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - cvc-enumeration-valid: Value '2.5' is not facet-valid with respect to enumeration '[2.4]'. It must be a value from the 
  enumeration.

Comment: That's a different problem. For example, you've set your IDE project facet version to 2.4 instead of 2.5.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10275/discussion-between-kshitij-and-balusc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've created a JSP EL function while you're using Facelets. This is not going to work. Also, your `<function-class>` declaration is incorrect. It should specify the full qualified class name (FQN). E.g. `com.example.FunctionClass`.

Rename the taglib file to `/WEB-INF/functions.taglib.xml` with the following updated content:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<facelet-taglib 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <namespace>http://example.com/functions</namespace>

    <function>
        <function-name>methodName</function-name>
        <function-class>com.example.FunctionClass</function-class>
        <function-signature>java.lang.String methodName(java.lang.String)</function-signature>
    </function>
</facelet-taglib>
```

Then you need to register it in `web.xml` as follows (don't forget to remove the old JSP taglib registration!):

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/functions.taglib.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Finally declare it in your view by the following XML namespace

```
xmlns:cx="http://example.com/functions"
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, there's an alternative approach, probably much easier: [install JBoss EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284236/jsf-2-0-method-invocation/3284328#3284328). This way you will be able to invoke methods on beans like as possible in the new EL 2.2.

Comment: i think i made mistake on web.xml

Answer (score 1):

You still need to include the reference in your jsp:

```
<%@taglib prefix="cx" uri="http://example.com/functions"%>
```

Comment: i am using facelets and and following ns i am using. xmlns:cx="http://example.com/functions"