# Retrieve h:inputHidden inside a p:commandButton action attribute

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I got a JSF 2.0 + PrimeFaces application and inside a h:form there's an inputHidden like this:

```
<h:inputHidden id="mdid" />
```

Unfortunately our managed beans come from another developer team and they had deployed a bean (@ViewScoped) in a .jar with an action method like this:

```
public void action(Integer id) {
    //Call service layer passing the id.
}
```

Our inputHidden is changed in client side and we can't bind it with bean.

Is there anyway I can do this?

```
<p:commandButton action="#{ServiceBean.action( mdid )}"
```

**mdid** should be replaced with inputHidden's value.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bind it to the view so that you can get its value in EL scope as well.

```html
<h:inputHidden id="mdid" binding="#{mdid}" />
...
<p:commandButton ... action="#{ServiceBean.action(mdid.value)}" />
```

Comment: Hi @BalusC, thanks, but I can't bind anything because we can't create anything in bean, just consume it, and bean contains only `public void action(Integer id)`.

Comment: The example in my answer doesn't bind it to the bean. It binds it to the view. Just use the exact syntax `binding="#{mdid}"` and thus **not** `binding="#{someBean.mdid}"`.

Comment: So you have an existing variable `#{mid}` which is a `String`? Give it a different and unique name. To be clear, you don't need to prepare any variables in view or in bean. The answer is just complete and as-is.

Comment: Sure, this binding works fine. There's now only one detail I'm missing. Tried a lot here but not success. Got it `action="#{ServiceBean.action(mdid.value)}" Failed to parse the expression [#{ServiceBean.action(mdid.value)}]`. However this works: `<h:outputText value="#{mdid.value}" />`

Comment: Then your environment apparently doesn't support EL 2.2. Make sure that you target a Servlet 3.0 compatible container (Tomcat 7, Glassfish 3, etc) with a `web.xml` which is declared conform Servlet 3.0 spec version. Otherwise, use JBoss EL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284236/jsf-2-0-method-invocation/3284328#3284328

Comment: That's it! My application was build under tomcat 6. I changed to tomcat 7 and works perfectly. Thanks a lot @BalusC.