# Basic JSF 2 and tomcat 6 action result navigation issue

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat6

I have a JSF 2.0 with mojara EL 2.2 on tomcat 6 and had it working for some time now during the development.
I recently added a form with a command button for login (basic stuff) which checks the username and password in the managed bean  at the action doLogin.

```
public String doLogin(){
    FacesMessage message = null;
    if((username.equals("user"))&&(password.equals("pass")))
        return "testpage.xhtml";
    else
        message = new FacesMessage("Invalid username or password");

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);

    return null;
}
```

The problem is that after it goes through doLogin and returns **"testpage.xhtml"** the same page is displayed. Even though I have all xhtml's file in the root of WebContent.

In the console of tomcat I get:

> The ELResolvers for JSF were not registered with the JSP container.

Passing parameters using EL 2.2 work fine.

I'm using JSF with Facelets.

Answer (score 0):

Implicit navigation is introduced since JSF 2.0. In old JSF 1.x you'd need to define a `<navigation-rule>` in `faces-config.xml` or to explicitly call `ExternalContext#redirect()` on an URL.

This problem suggests that your JSF 2.0 web application is running in JSF 1.x fallback modus. Make sure that your `faces-config.xml` is declared conform JSF 2.0 specification version.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <!-- Config here. -->

</faces-config>
```

The EL resolver warning is unrelated to this this. It's caused by using Glassfish's EL 2.2 on Tomcat 6 and you would be unable to use EL in `.jsp` pages (which shouldn't be a problem if you're solely using Facelets). If you want to get rid of this warning, use [JBoss EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284236/jsf-2-0-method-invocation/3284328#3284328) instead of Glassfish EL. JBoss EL is an enhanced EL 2.1 implementation while Glassfish EL is an EL 2.2 implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, B'coz I don't see another code.

If you don't set specific navigation-rule in faces-config.xml.

Default of $SUB-DIRECTORY1/testpage.xhtml is $SUB-DIRECTORY1/testpage

Answer (score 0):

In JSF 2.0 testpage view translated into implicit navigation. Please change your code likes here,

```
    public String doLogin(){
       FacesMessage message = null;
       if((username.equals("user"))&&(password.equals("pass"))) {
            return "testpage";
       } else {
            message = new FacesMessage("Invalid username or password");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
       }
    return null;
}
```