# Running JSF page Error: Failed to parse the expression [${LogModel.getLogList()}]?

Tags: parsing, jsf, tomcat

I am using jsf 2 along with tomcat 6, and I am trying to execute this code which is in a .xhtml page that I have:

```
    <h:dataTable value="${LogModel.getLogList()}" var="c"
            styleClass="order-table"
            headerClass="order-table-header"
            rowClasses="order-table-odd-row,order-table-even-row"
        >
```

I do have the class logmodel and the method getLogList(), however I get this error when i launch the page:

**/testLog.xhtml @20,8 value="${LogModel.getLogList()}" Failed to parse the expression [${LogModel.getLogList()}]**

Here is the complete log of the problem:

```
javax.faces.view.facelets.TagAttributeException: /testLog.xhtml @20,8 value="${LogModel.getLogList()}" Failed to parse the expression [${LogModel.getLogList()}]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl.getValueExpression(TagAttributeImpl.java:401)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl.getValueExpression(TagAttributeImpl.java:351)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentRule$ValueExpressionMetadata.applyMetadata(ComponentRule.java:107)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.MetadataImpl.applyMetadata(MetadataImpl.java:81)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.MetaTagHandler.setAttributes(MetaTagHandler.java:129)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.setAttributes(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:102)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.doNewComponentActions(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:398)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:159)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:184)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:152)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:769)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:100)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression [${LogModel.getLogList()}]
    at org.apache.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.createNodeInternal(ExpressionBuilder.java:146)
    at org.apache.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.build(ExpressionBuilder.java:172)
    at org.apache.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.createValueExpression(ExpressionBuilder.java:216)
    at org.apache.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.createValueExpression(ExpressionFactoryImpl.java:68)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl.getValueExpression(TagAttributeImpl.java:385)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: org.apache.el.parser.ParseException: Encountered " "(" "( "" at line 1, column 22.
Was expecting one of:
    "}" ...
    "." ...
    "[" ...
    ">" ...
    "gt" ...
    "<" ...
    "lt" ...
    ">=" ...
    "ge" ...
    "<=" ...
    "le" ...
    "==" ...
    "eq" ...
"!=" ...
"ne" ...
"&&" ...
"and" ...
"||" ...
"or" ...
"*" ...
"+" ...
"-" ...
"/" ...
"div" ...
"%" ...
"mod" ...

at org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.generateParseException(ELParser.java:2142)
at org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.jj_consume_token(ELParser.java:2024)
at org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.DynamicExpression(ELParser.java:147)
at org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.CompositeExpression(ELParser.java:43)
at org.apache.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.createNodeInternal(ExpressionBuilder.java:114)
... 38 more
```

Your kind help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The EL syntax `${LogModel.getLogList()}` is only supported since EL 2.2 which goes along with Servlet 3.0. But you're using the old Tomcat 6 server which is a Servlet 2.5 container which implies EL 2.1. You need to use the normal EL 2.1 syntax then.

```
${LogModel.logList}
```

If you really insist in using the new EL 2.2 syntax of invoking action methods, then you could always install JBoss EL as described in this answer: [Invoke direct methods or methods with arguments / variables / parameters in EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284236/jsf-2-0-method-invocation/3284328#3284328) However, this makes no sense for a simple getter method which could then be accessed by a simpler EL syntax.

A major misconception among starters is that they think that this new EL 2.2 syntax is specific to JSF 2.0. But this is thus actually not true. This confusion is caused because both EL 2.2 and JSF 2.0 are part of Java EE 6, but JSF 2.0 itself is backwards compatible with Java EE 5 (Servlet 2.5, EL 2.1, etc).

Comment: thanks a lot, I made your answer as best because it is very comprehansive :) even though the other one was completely right. Anyway, the problem of "failed to parse" have gone, but I did not know how to test it, this is what I did:
I have put this code in the .xhtml file 
<h2><h:outputText id="output" value="#{logBean.sayWelcome}" /></h2>

to test this function in logbean class:

public String getSayWelcome(){
     //check if null?
    
   return "Ajax message : Welcome ";
     }
however, nothing is being returned :( in the display.

Answer (score 1):

1) It is `#`, not `$`

2) Delete the brackets `()` and the `get`. You are using the properties, not the methods (even if you need to define them in your class).

3) Most probably, the bean name must also begin with lowerCase (you are accessing an object, not a class).

```
value="#{logModel.logList}"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked perfectly, I have updated my tomcat to 7 and method invocation has worked :)