# Does not ui:repeat's value method (with parameter) work when ajax request?

Tags: java, jsf-2

When `mypage.xhtml` load for the first time, `#{DashBoard.getResvDataModelList(date, meetingRoom)}` work well. When ajax request of `h:commandLink`, `date`  and    `meetingRoom` instance is null.
That's why, I get `NullPointerException` in my `getResvDataModelList(Date date, MeetingRoom meetingRoom)` method.

How can I solve this problem? My situation is I have to use `page parameter` in `ui:repeat` value method.
Could you provide the another solution?

---

If I remove `<ui:repeat value="#{DashBoard.getResvDataModelList(date, meetingRoom)}" var="model" >`, my page is work well with ajax request.

---

Cause :

```
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.5.Final.jar:2.0.5.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    ... 38 more
```

mymethod

```
public List<ResvDataModel> getResvDataModelList(Date date, MeetingRoom meetingRoom) {
    logger.debug("getResvDataModelList() ====> " + formatter.format(date) + " : " + meetingRoom.getName());
}
```

mypage.xhtml

```
<h:commandLink action="#{DashBoard.increase()}" value="NextWeek" immediate="true" >
    <f:ajax execute="@this" render="dashboard" />
</h:commandLink>

<h:panelGroup id="dashboard">
    <table style="margin-top:-1px;" class="dashboard">
        <ui:repeat value="#{DashBoard.dateList}" var="date">
            <tr>
                <td style="background:#DBEAF9;">
                    <h:outputText value="#{date}" style="color:#333333;font-size:13px;">
                        <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="EEE, yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                    </h:outputText>
                </td>
                <ui:repeat value="#{DashBoard.timeSlot}" var="timeSlot" >
                    <td style="background:#DBEAF9;text-align: center;width:70px;">
                        <h:outputText value="#{timeSlot}" style="font-size:12px;"/>
                    </td>
                </ui:repeat>
            </tr>
            <ui:repeat value="#{DashBoard.resourceList}" var="meetingRoom">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h:outputText value="#{meetingRoom.name}" style="font-size:12px;"/>
                    </td>
                    <ui:repeat value="#{DashBoard.getResvDataModelList(date, meetingRoom)}" var="model" >
                        <td>
                            <h:outputText value="#{model.id}" style="font-size:11px;"/>
                        </td>
                    </ui:repeat>
                </tr>
            </ui:repeat>
        </ui:repeat>
    </table>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: What JSF impl/version are you using? I can't reproduce your problem based on the information provided so far with Mojarra 2.1.13. But I know that nesting `<ui:repeat>`s has exposed various bugs during the first year of Mojarra versions (state saving for postbacks is totally wrong). Perhaps you're using an old Mojarra version and you just need to upgrade?

Comment: That's just the JSF specification version. I was asking for JSF implementation and its version. There are 2 major JSF implementations: Mojarra (from Sun/Oracle) and MyFaces (from Apache). The `com.sun.faces` in the stacktrace indicates that you're using Mojarra. But which version? Try upgrading to latest.