# Does method parameters of ui:repeat work in JSF postback request?

Tags: jsf, el

Does method parameters of `ui:repeat` work in JSF postback request?

Example :

```
<ui:repeat value="#{mybean.method(param, data.param)}"/>
```

When I test it, it is not work in Postback request.

Comment: @Pradeep, I test Weblogic 10.2 and JBoss 7.1.1_Final

Comment: is there error getting in console

Comment: When `Postback action`, the method will get `null` of `parameter`. There is no error in console.

Comment: @CycDemo: Please stop formatting non-code as code. Use code formatting for code only. Phrases like "method parameters", "postback request", "parameter", etc are **not** code. Code is whatever you've actually placed in your real code, such as `ui:repeat`, `null`, etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does not ui:repeat's value method (with parameter) work when ajax request?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12884049/does-not-uirepeats-value-method-with-parameter-work-when-ajax-request)