# How to compare a char property in EL

Tags: jsf, char, el

I have a command button like below.

```
<h:commandButton value="Accept orders" action="#{acceptOrdersBean.acceptOrder}"
   styleClass="button" rendered="#{product.orderStatus=='N' }"></h:commandButton>
```

even when the `product.orderStatus` value is equal to `'N'` the command button is not displayed in my page.

Here `product.orderStatus` is a character property.

Comment: Is `product` a bean name?

Comment: What do you see when you add this to your page <h:outputText value="orderstatsu= #{product.orderStatus}"/>. Is it N or something else?

Comment: @Matt:yes product here is a bean name

Comment: @roel: i can see N only.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is, unfortunately, expected behavior. In EL, anything in quotes like `'N'` is always treated as a `String` and a `char` property value is always treated as a number. The `char` is in EL represented by its Unicode codepoint, which is `78` for `N`.

There are two *workarounds*:

1. Use `String#charAt()`, passing `0`, to get the `char` out of a `String` in EL. Note that this works only if your environment supports EL 2.2. Otherwise you need to install [JBoss EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284236/jsf-2-0-method-invocation/3284328#3284328).

   ```html
   <h:commandButton ... rendered="#{product.orderStatus eq 'N'.charAt(0)}">
   ```
2. Use the char's numeric representation in Unicode, which is 78 for `N`. You can figure out the right Unicode codepoint by `System.out.println((int) 'N')`.

   ```html
   <h:commandButton ... rendered="#{product.orderStatus eq 78}">
   ```

The **real solution**, however, is to use an [enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html):

```
public enum OrderStatus {
     N, X, Y, Z;
}
```

with

```
private OrderStatus orderStatus; // +getter
```

then you can use exactly the desired syntax in EL:

```html
<h:commandButton ... rendered="#{product.orderStatus eq 'N'}">
```

Additional bonus is that enums enforce type safety. You won't be able to assign an aribtrary character like `☆` or `웃` as order status value.

Comment: My test case with `private char testChar = 'N';` + getter/setter and with `<h:commandButton action=".." value="TestButton" rendered="#{sessionBean.testChar == 'N'}"/>` worked perfectly. The button is hidden if I change the test to `sessionBean.testChar == 'J'`.

Comment: @Matt: What EL impl are you using?

Comment: It is Glassfish 3.1.2 with no extra libs installed. Must be 2.2, correct?

Comment: @Matt: Apparently they enhanced(?) their EL impl. It fails in Tomcat as per EL spec.