# JSF char comparison does not work as expected

Tags: java, jsf, char, el, logical-operators

I have a JSF page which i control the renderer attribute according to managed bean property.

```
<p:commandLink action="#{smartphoneBean.drillDown(smartphone.ldapuser,smartphone.productGrp)}"
                            rendered="#{!(smartphone.ldapuser.charAt(0) ge '0' and smartphone.ldapuser.charAt(0) le '9')}"  value="#{smartphone.ldapuser}">
```

Once i run my code. this commandLink whose values starts with any number is still rendered.

I expect to compare integer representation of char values.

do you have any idea about the issue?

Comment: you are trying to compare `charAt(0)` with `ge / le` ? first convert that `charAt(0)` to a number and remove the `''` around those numbers...

Comment: You can create a `Boolean` variable in the Bean class. Do this comparison in bean class and set Boolean variable to `true` or `false`. Use that variable in the rendered.

Comment: @Daniel as far as i know. char data types are represented as integer in the JVM. that's why i compare char values. i expect to compare unicode decimal values.

Comment: @SatheshS i use this commandLink in the dataTable, so it will be propagated iteratively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`String#charAt(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29) returns a `char` (an Unicode codepoint) which is in EL interpreted as [`Number`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html). The `'0'` is evaluated as `String`, not as `Number`. So the comparisons will always yield undesired results.

The characters `0` to `9` have the Unicode codepoints of [48 to 57](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Codepage_layout). So, this should do:

```
rendered="#{!(smartphone.ldapuser.charAt(0) ge 48 and smartphone.ldapuser.charAt(0) le 57)}"  value="#{smartphone.ldapuser}">
```

#### See also:

- [How to compare a char property in EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14454261/rendered-attribute-not-working-on-a-character-property/14457612#14457612)

Comment: As expected BalusC answers all JSF questions. Thank you very much.