# EL Expression error on JBoss EAP 6.1

Tags: jsf-2, jboss

I've the following EL Expression that is throwing an error and I'm trying to figure out a workaround for this.
The expression is `#{usr.resetPwd eq 'S'}`

`usr.resetPwd` is of type java.lang.Character, and in GlassFish the expression resolves to java.lang.String, but, apparently, JBoss resolves it to java.lang.Long, and fails to interpret correctly the expression.

The error is `Cannot convert S of type java.lang.String to java.lang.Long`

I can make the expression work by changing the type of resetPwd, or by changing the expression to `#{usr.resetPwd.toString() eq 'S'}`, but I wanted to avoid having to verify and change all the applications. Is there any configuration or better approach to make the applications behave the same way when running on JBoss or GlassFish?

Kind regards,

Carlos Ferreira

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rendered attribute not working on a character property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14454261/rendered-attribute-not-working-on-a-character-property)

Comment: Summarized: use the right tool for the job, use an enum.

Comment: In link you've provided, they mention that this is the expected behavior, which is odd because GlassFish does not follow this rule. I cannot use an enum, because resetPwd is a property from an Entity bean, and this kind of expressions are used in many other situations.

Comment: Just subclass the model and fix it there.

Comment: Or better, fix the entity and the remainder immediately. It was simply poorly designed from the beginning on.