# <c:if> not working for comparing characters

Tags: jsp, char, jstl, el

`<c:if>` is  not working for comparing characters.The code is inside a table.Here is the code

```
<c:if test="${record.type eq 'U' }">Planned</c:if>
```

When I use this code inside the table,the table content is not displayed.Please help!

Comment: did you declaired jstl? i.e. `<%@ taglib prefi x=”c” uri=”http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core” %>`

Comment: Better use enums instead of chars. You can compare enums the "normal" way (exactly like as in your current attempt). Here's a more elaborate answer in JSF context: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14454261/rendered-attribute-not-working-on-a-character-property/14457612#14457612

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Issue is EL supports both double and single quoted Strings. So `'U'` is taken as `String`, not `char`. To resolve the issue, you can use `charAt(0)` method on that String:

```
<c:if test="${record.type eq 'U'.charAt(0) }">Planned</c:if>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
`<c:if test="${'U'.toString() eq 'U'}">demo</c:if>`
```

It works for me since instead of first 'U', I was getting the list of Characters. So the type should be converted to String first.)

Answer (score 0):

check the value of `${record.type}`
print it on jsp

becuse

```
<c:if test="${'U' eq 'U'}">demo</c:if>
```

it works for me in jsp

or if you have some version conflict then

try below one it may help

```
<c:if test = "${record.type == 'U'}">demo</c:if>
```

but make sure the value of `${record.type}`