# conditional statement with expression language that is not ternary

Tags: el

I need to make an expression language conditional statement with a few conditions to check. Googling I can only find examples using ternary

```
#{SomeBean.someProperty ? 'bob' : 'John'}
```

I need to have more conditions though. I need something like:

```
If (SomeBean.someProperty == 'a'){
   //Ant
}
Else if (SomeBean.someProperty == 'b'){
   //Bob
}
Else if (SomeBean.someProperty == 'c'){
   //C++
}
Else{
   //Back to the drawing board, something went wrong.
}
```

How can I write this in expression language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just the same syntax as in plain Java.

```
#{bean.property eq 'a' ? 'Ant' : bean.property eq 'b' ? 'Bob' : bean.property eq 'c' ? 'C++' : null}
```

Do note that `property` is assumed to be `String` or `enum` and not `char` because a `char` is interpreted the same way as numbers in EL. See also [How to compare a char property in EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14454261/how-to-compare-a-char-property-in-el).