# Call different actions from same command in JSF 2

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I don't know if this is a good practice but I would like to call different actions on managed beans from the same `commandButton` depending on the user context. The reason is that I access a page from different locations in the application, and I want my single command be a sort of "Back" button to the locations I came from.
I've implemented a custom mechanism based on the idea of MyFaces Orchestra Flow with redirect in a custom NavigationHandler but I wonder if there is a way to parameterized the `action` attribute of my commandButton.

Any suggestions welcome

Comment: Are you using JSF 2.x or 1.2? You mixed both tags on the question which is quite confusing.

Comment: Currently JSF 2.x ; I thought maybe it exists a standard mechanism in the two versions.

Comment: You could make two buttons and set the **rendered** property showing the button you need or not.

Comment: Yes, this was my first solution but I was looking for something less intrusive by reusing existing facelets, ManagedBean and navigation rules.

Answer (score 1):

If your target environment supports Servlet 3.0 / EL 2.2 (Tomcat 7, Glassfish 3, etc), or has [JBoss EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284236/jsf-2-0-method-invocation/3284328#3284328) installed, then you can just pass the deisred argument directly into the method. So you can just have

```
public void submit(String argument) {
    // ...
}
```

and

```html
<h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{bean.submit('some')}" />
```

or, based on an EL scoped variable:

```html
<h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{bean.submit(some)}" />
```

There are other ways though. Think of `<f:param>`, `<f:setPropertyActionListener>`, `Application#evaluateExpressionGet()`, etc. Many of them are answered in context of `<h:dataTable>` here: [How can I pass selected row to commandLink inside dataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994458/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-commandlink-inside-a-datatable/4994833#4994833) (the principle is not that different when outside data table)

Comment: Thank you very much for the response but these requirements are not satisfied for me. However I'm not sure this will work because what I want is really : "#{bean1.method1}" or "#{bean2.method2}" and take advantage of the navigation rules associated with these action.

Comment: Just let the method delegate to the desired method and return the desired outcome? E.g. `if ("foo".equals(argument)) { return bean1.method1(); } else { return bean2.method2(); }`.