# primefaces OrderedList does not store the row selected

Tags: jsf, primefaces

The value selected does not seem to get stored in the variable `theme`.  The method `updatCandidateSelect` gives me a `nullexception` error.

```
<p:orderList value="#{badgeController.listCandidat}" var="theme" itemLabel="# 
{theme.compte.nom}" itemValue="#{theme.compte.nom}"  controlsLocation="left" 
responsive="true">
<p:ajax event="select" listener="# 
{badgeController.updateCandidatSelect(theme)}" />
                           </p:orderList>
```

here's my managedBean code

```
@ManagedBean(name = "badgeController")
@SessionScoped
public class BadgeController {

 private BadgeScanner badge;
 private List<CandidatSelectionne> listCandidat;
 private List<LogIn> listRecruteur;
 private int numSelected;
 private boolean favoris;
 private List<String>nomCandidat;
 private CandidatSelectionne candidat;

 @EJB
 private BadgeFacade badgeFacade;

 @EJB
 CandidatSelectionneFacade candidatFacade;
 public void updateCandidatSelect(CandidatSelectionne selection){


 System.out.println("le nom de la 
 selection"+selection.getCompte().getNom());
 candidat=new CandidatSelectionne();
 candidat = selection;
 System.out.println("candidat selectionne son compte : " 
 +candidat.getCompte().getNom());
 System.out.println("candidat selectionne son recruteur : 
 "+candidat.getRecruteur().getEmail());

 }
```

without the getters and setters

Comment: What JSF version are you using? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16485487/jsf-action-method-with-variable-parameter

Comment: Please put the code of your ManagedBean to see if there is something wrong in it.

Comment: Please put a [mcve]

Comment: I have added the ManagedBean code.