# How to pass a parameter to backing bean using EL expression in JSF component?

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2

I have this component:

```
<t:outputText value="#{bean.name}">
```

I want to call a method **with a parameter** in the EL expression instead of calling a getter, but I don't have JSF 2.0.

How can I pass a parameter to a method in the backing bean using EL
expression without JSF 2.0?

In other words, I want to do something like this:

```
 <t:outputText value="#{bean.findName(#{bean.name})}">
```

**Outer expression**: To call a method with a parameter in the backing bean.

**Inner expression**: To call a getter to use as a parameter in the method.

The method in the backing bean:

```
public String findName(String name){


}
```

Thanks ahead! :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invoke direct methods or methods with arguments / variables / parameters in EL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284236/invoke-direct-methods-or-methods-with-arguments-variables-parameters-in-jsf)

Comment: Important note which everyone seems to fail to see: feature is not specific to JSF 2.0, but to EL 2.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method parameters are a feature of EL 2.2 so you need to download the appropriate JARs and add them to your project. If you are using Maven go to this link

https://uel.java.net/download.html

(or go straight to Maven central)

Then add the following in web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
</context-param>
```

**EDIT**

This is a follow up from your comment. You could do something like this.

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.id}">  <---This one will set the id
<h:outputText value="#{bean.name}"> <--- This one will display the name
```

and define your methods like this

```
private Integer id; //Make setter and getter
private String name; //Make setter and getter for this. 

private Integer setId(Integer id) { //Make a getter also
   name = findName(id); // <--- Set the name property there
}

public String findName(Integer id) { 

    return name found in db; 

}
```

This is just an idea.

Comment: When using older application servers, it may also be necessary to install JBoss EL. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3284328/1713801.