# Create a list of selectBooleanCheckbox using ui:repeat

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have one doubt about create `selectBooleanCheckbox` using `ui:repeat`.

I have one class called `Filter` whith theses `fields`.

```
class Filter {

    private Boolean comissaoAdesao;
    private Boolean comissaoSaque;
    private Boolean comissaoSaqueAdicional;
    private Boolean comissaoCompra;
    private Boolean cidadeUF;
    private Boolean publicidade;

    // getter e setter
}
```

So I want to know if is possible to link the fields to `selectBooleanCheckbox` using `ui:repeat`.

My method is:

```
if (NullUtil.isNull(this.colunasAnalitico)) {
    Map<String, Boolean> map = new TreeMap<String, Boolean>() {
        {
            put("Comissão adesão", filter.getComissaoAdesao());
            put("Comissão saque", filter.getComissaoSaque());
            put("Comissão saque adicional", filter.getComissaoSaqueAdicional());
            put("Comissão compra", filter.getComissaoCompra());
            put("Cidade/UF", filter.getCidadeUF());
            put("Publicidade", filter.getPublicidade());
        }
    };
    this.colunasAnalitico = new ArrayList<Entry<String, Boolean>>(map.entrySet());
}
return colunasAnalitico;
```

And my page code is:

```
<ui:repeat >
    <p:row>
        <c:set var="campo" value="bean.filter.#{colunaAnalitico.value}"/>
        <p:column style="width: 2%">
            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox label="#{colunaAnalitico.key}" value="#{campo}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <p:outputLabel value="#{campo}"/>
        </p:column>                         
    </p:row>
</ui:repeat>
```

Comment: how `<ui:repeat/>` will decide how many `<p:selectBooleanCheckbox>`  render in the page ?

Comment: The size of `this.colunasAnalitico`

Comment: See this answer related to `<ui:repeat>` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6741573/how-map-multiple-inputtext-to-an-array-property

Comment: But how can I link with a field in the other `class`, because each `label` has one `boolean` field.

Comment: `<ui:repeat>` You have to pass `List` simple then it automatically bind the values

Answer (score 4):

Simply put: the view must match the model.

In your current model, you've a bunch of **fixed** boolean properties, not a dynamically sized array or collection of boolean properties. The `<ui:repeat>` can only iterate over a dynamically sized array or collection. In your model, you already know all possible boolean properties beforehand. So, you can just define them all in the view. Technically, you don't need an `<ui:repeat>` at all. Your initial attempt with `value="#{someBoolean}"` instead of `value="#{bean.someBoolean}"` failed for same technical reason as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10780858/using-uirepeathinputtext-on-a-liststring-doesnt-update-model-values/).

Given an example entity of

```
public class Filter {

    private Boolean option1;
    private Boolean option2;
    private Boolean option3;

    // ...
}
```

You can just do so:

```
<p:panelGrid columns="2">
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="option1" value="#{bean.filter.option1}" />
    <p:outputLabel for="option1" value="Filter option one" />

    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="option2" value="#{bean.filter.option2}" />
    <p:outputLabel for="option2" value="Filter option two" />

    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="option3" value="#{bean.filter.option3}" />
    <p:outputLabel for="option3" value="Filter option three" />
</p:panelGrid>
```

In case you was concerned about non-[DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) code, simply put this all in a reusable [include file or perhaps even tagfile or composite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen) taking `#{bean.filter}` as value.

```
<my:selectFilterOptions value="#{bean.filter}" />
```

In case you was concerned about the label values for some reason, you need to realize that they don't belong in the model at all. They belong in the view, or at least in a resource bundle properties file.

```
filter_option.option1 = Filter option one
filter_option.option2 = Filter option two
filter_option.option3 = Filter option three
```

```
<p:outputLabel for="option1" value="#{i18n['filter_option.option1']}" />
...
<p:outputLabel for="option2" value="#{i18n['filter_option.option2']}" />
...
<p:outputLabel for="option3" value="#{i18n['filter_option.option3']}" />
```

#### See also:

- [Internationalization in JSF, when to use message-bundle and resource-bundle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668161/when-to-use-message-bundle-and-resource-bundle/)

---

From the other side on, it's also very good possible that the model is simply poorly designed. The most straightforward refactoring approach of a bunch of fixed booleans would be an `enum`.

```
public enum FilterOption {

    OPTION1,
    OPTION2,
    OPTION3;

}
```

You can simply hold them in an array or a collection (an array is easier so you don't need a JSF converter; in case you'd like to use JPA `@ElementCollection` on an `@Enumerated` and thus can't use an array, consider [OmniFaces `GenericEnumConverter`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/GenericEnumConverter)).

```
public class Filter {

    private FilterOption[] options;

    // ...
}
```

You can supply all available values in the application scope.

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class Data {

    public FilterOption[] getFilterOptions() {
        return FilterOption.values();
    }

}
```

You can localize labels in a resource bundle properties file using enum names as keys.

```
filter_option.OPTION1 = Filter option one
filter_option.OPTION2 = Filter option two
filter_option.OPTION3 = Filter option three
```

So you can ultimately use a `<p:selectManyCheckbox>` instead of `<p:panelGrid><p:selectBooleanCheckbox>`.

```
<p:selectManyCheckbox value="#{bean.filter.options}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{data.filterOptions}" var="option"
        itemValue="#{option}" itemLabel="#{i18n['filter_option.' += option]}" />
</p:selectManyCheckbox>
```

#### See also:

- [How to use enum values in f:selectItem(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229638/how-to-make-a-dropdown-menu-of-a-enum-in-jsf/)
- [Use enum in h:selectManyCheckbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822058/use-enum-in-hselectmanycheckbox/)
- [How do I get selectManyCheckBox to return something other than List<String>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294284/how-do-i-get-selectmanycheckbox-to-return-something-other-than-liststring/)

Comment: Very good, but I have one doubt, if I want to use the boolean values to render or not a column. Wich option will be better?

Comment: Not sure what the concrete problem is.

Comment: I asked if I used these boolean values to render or columns in one panelgrid, your solution will be the best?

Comment: Still not sure what the concrete problem is. As answered, the best solution is that the view matches the model. You can check anything in `rendered` attribute as long as the EL expression evaluates to a `boolean`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/4870557

Answer (score 1):

What you need for your use case is a [SelectManyCheckbox](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/manyCheckbox.xhtml)

Looking at your code, you can use it somewhat like this:

```
<p:selectManyCheckbox id="basic" value="#{yourBean.selectedCheckboxes}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{yourBean.colunaAnalitico}" var="item" itemLabel="#{item.key}" itemValue="#{item.value}" />
</p:selectManyCheckbox>
```

You can even throw in a `<ui:param name="campo" value="(what you want to do with item.value that I can't understand from your code)" />` if you need it...

Comment: I changed my answer because I have a `Filter` class, that a I link each `label` with that `field` in `Filter class`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a bit strange, check if this meets your requirements:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.map.entrySet().toArray()}" var="entry" >
    <p:row>
        <p:column style="width: 2%">
            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox label="#{entry.key}" value="#{bean.map[entry.key]}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <p:outputLabel value="#{entry.key}"/>
        </p:column>                         
    </p:row>
</ui:repeat>
```

`bean` is your backing bean and `map` may be `TreeMap<String, Boolean>`. This worked for me so should also for you.

**Related**

- [Pushing a value from inside <ui:repeat> in a map, set or list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18203481/pushing-a-value-from-inside-uirepeat-in-a-map-set-or-list)

Comment: I used your example, but the value of the boolean array didn´t updated.

Comment: You need submit button, `p:commandButton` for example and then this should work.