# How to use a map key in EL which is a concatenation of static string and EL variable

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, el

I have a `<p:dataTable var="object">` with a `<p:commandLink>` inside. In my bean I have a `Map` whose value I want to display in `<p:commandLink value>` . I need to pass a key to this map which is a concatenation of `"someString"` and `#{object.firstName}`. I would something like this to work:

```
value="#{bean.map['someString'+object.firstName]}"
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can concatenate strings in EL by creating a new EL variable with the string and EL expression just inlined. You can use `<c:set>` for that.

```
<c:set var="key" value="someString#{object.firstName}" />
<p:commandLink value="#{bean.map[key]}" ... />
```

Alternatively, if you're on EL 2.2 already which supports invoking direct methods, then you can just directly make use of [`String#concat()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#concat%28java.lang.String%29) method.

```
<p:commandLink value="#{bean.map['someString'.concat(object.firstName)]}" ... />
```

If you're not on EL 2.2 yet, but are using EL 2.1, then you can always install [JBoss EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284236/invoke-direct-methods-or-methods-with-arguments-variables-parameters-in-el/3284328#3284328) to have the same feature.

Comment: Thanx a lot BalusC.Will test and let u know my findings.

Answer (score 0):

Mr AC_1985 didn't respond but for information I have some working code along these lines.

```
                            <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="5" style="width:100%">
                                <p:inputTextarea id="factsText" style="width:100%; height:100%;" rows="18" cols="100" 
                                value="#{property.model.property.facts[property.model.factsLanguage.code]}"
                                counter="display" maxlength="2000" counterTemplate="{0} characters remaining." autoResize="false" />
                                <h:outputText id="display" />
                            </h:panelGrid>
```

Here I have a combo box where I can select a language. Then the text is retrieved from the Map for the language selected.

Thanks My BalusC for your invaluable help, as always.

Allan