# Pagination on JSF using get parameters

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, get

I am on index.xhtml and I have this code snippet:

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton action="#{blogentryListerBean.olderBlogEntries}"
                     value="Older Blog Entries"/>
</h:form>
```

BlogEntryListerBean is **RequestScoped**. This is the code I have in **olderBlogEntries**

```
public String olderBlogEntries() {

    HttpServletRequest request
            = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();

    String id = request.getParameter("id");

    if (id == null || id.equals("")) {
        id = "0";
    }

    int pageIamOn = Integer.valueOf(id);

    String stringToBeReturned = "index.xhtml?id=" + (pageIamOn + 1) + "&faces-redirect=true";
    return stringToBeReturned;
}
```

So when I hit index.xhtml for the first time the URL I see is: index.xhtml as expected.
The first time I click button "Older Blog Entries" I see URL: index.xhtml?id=1 
Now when I hit Older Blog Entries button, I am again on index.xhtml?id=1

What is wrong here? Why am I not going to index.xhtml?id=2

?

Thanks.

Comment: but maybe you need the specify the id ant tag command button..

Comment: you 're trying to recuperate a html tag with request.getParameter("id")..where is this parameter? always be null? so always be at pag 1..sorry if I don't understand correctly

Comment: No, you do understand correctly. It is the situation. It is always null. But I do not understand why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're actually misunderstanding the current Http lifecycle. Your problem basically is destination page (for your case *index.xhtml* itself) is not catching the sent param anywhere.

Remember you're performing a redirection at first, but when you press the button next time, it's currently another different request which knows nothing about your param, so, when the action is processed, your `request.getParameter("id")` returns `null` once and again as the param is not being sent.

Your problem has an easy solution, which is based in binding the received param to your view using `f:viewParam`:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="id" />
    </f:metadata>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h:commandButton action="#{bean.olderBlogEntries(id)}"
            value="Older Blog Entries" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

And your java code would be like this:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Bean {

    public String olderBlogEntries(Integer id) {

        if (id == null) {
            id = 0;
        }

        String stringToBeReturned = "index.xhtml?id=" + (id + 1)
                + "&faces-redirect=true";
        return stringToBeReturned;
    }
}
```

In this case you need to pass a parameter to an action method, to do like that you need to have EL 2.2 available in your classpath. If you don't have it already set up, follow [that steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284236/invoke-direct-methods-or-methods-with-arguments-variables-parameters-in-el/3284328#3284328).

The lifecycle woud be:

- First request, you open the browser and perform a GET request against index.xhtml. No param is sent.
- You press the button once, submitting the form as a POST request. The action method redirects to `http://localhost:8080/basic-jsf/index.xhtml?id=1`, which causes a GET request to be done by the client to this url. Now JSF catches the `id` view param and binds it to the view with the name `id`.
- When you press the button again, JSF calls the action method with the current param, valued `1`. The redirection now goes to `http://localhost:8080/basic-jsf/index.xhtml?id=2`.

**Alternatively**, you could bind the view param to a bean property. In that case, there would be no need to pass it as method parameter:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{bean.id}" />
    </f:metadata>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h:commandButton action="#{bean.olderBlogEntries}"
            value="Older Blog Entries" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Implementing your property's get/set methods:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Bean {

    private Integer id = 0;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String olderBlogEntries() {
        String stringToBeReturned = "index.xhtml?id=" + (id + 1)
                + "&faces-redirect=true";
        return stringToBeReturned;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
        System.out.println("id " + id + " received");
    }
}
```

**See also:**

- [What can <f:metadata>, <f:viewParam> and <f:viewAction> be used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-and-fviewparam-be-used-for)