# How to redirect to same page with all parameters?

Tags: jsf, redirect, jsf-2, parameters, query-string

In my app I have JSF page with some parameters

(url of example page: `/pages/user.xhtml?id=123&userToShowId=2`)

On this page i have a `commandButton`. After click it I want to redirect to the same page with all parameters. I know, that for this specified page I can do this manually this way:

```
public String redirect(){
    //extCtx - ExternalContext
    //ctx - FacesContext
    Map<String,String> param = extCtx.getRequestParameterMap();
    String currentURL = ctx.getViewRoot().getViewId();
    return currentURL+"?userToShowId="+param.get("userToShowId")+"&id="+param.get("id");
}
```

But what to do when I want to get universal way to redirect from any page with any parameters?

---

If I have view parameters only at pages, without set it as a bean property:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="backurl"/>
    <f:viewParam name="id"/>
</f:metadata>
```

not with `value`:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="backurl" value=#{bean.id}/>
    <f:viewParam name="id" value=#{bean.id}/>
</f:metadata>
```

can I use `includeViewParams=true` to do my work?

Comment: Do you mean you want to blindly include view request parameters with any request *throughout* your webapp? You'll need a custom navigation handler for that

Comment: I have commandButton to change language at all page. When I click this button I have to make some backing bean code (to change lang) and come back to the same page. But when there is some parameter at page where  i click the button, after make bean code i lose every parameters.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20728072/pagination-on-jsf-using-get-parameters).

Comment: @XtremeBiker i see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20728072/pagination-on-jsf-using-get-parameters), but i use `f:viewParam`. Do you mean I have to add this parameters to beans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without having to bind them to the managed bean. In JSF there are two main navigation cases:

- Perform a view request without doing nothing more. That's an **HTTP GET** request and is done using `h:button`, which doesn't need to be wrapped by a form and acts like a link.
- Perform a form **POST** and after that ask for another page (**REDIRECT-GET**), that's done by `h:commandButton`.

You can include view params in both cases. That's how it's done:

```xhtml
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head />
<h:body>
    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="backurl" />
        <f:viewParam name="id" />
    </f:metadata>
    <h:outputText value="backurl value is #{backurl} and id value is #{id}" />
    <br />
    <h:button outcome="index" value="redirect">
        <f:param name="backurl" value="directUrl" />
        <f:param name="id" value="directId" />
    </h:button>
    <h:form>
        <h:commandButton value="action" action="#{bean.redirect}" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

```java
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
// You could also use @ViewScoped
public class Bean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * Performs a redirection to index destination view with the given params
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public String redirect() {
        return "index?backurl=actionUrl&id=actionId&faces-redirect=true";
    }
}
```

You'll see when you initially load the page, both `backurl` and `id` don't have a value.

The first button performs a *GET* request with fixed view parameter values. When view loads again, values are already there. Second button does the same but using an action method.

Keep in mind that using `@RequestScoped` or `@ViewScoped` here has the same effect, as `@RequestScoped` doesn't maintain the state of the bean and `@ViewScoped` destroys it each time an `String` value is returned from the method, which is happening every time we invoke it.

Comment: but what can I do when I don't know parameter name but I want to reload page?

Comment: And I have to redirect to the same page, no other. In other word, I want to refresh page and don't lose parameter value.

Comment: Just replace the fixed values you're sending by `#{backurl}` and `#{id}` for the `h:button` case. For the action method, you can change the no-parametered `#{bean.redirect}` by `#{bean.redirect(backurl,id)}` and make it receive two `String` parameters at server side (if you're using EL 2.2, which makes possible passing parameters). Then, perform the redirection with that received parameters.

Comment: I want to get universal way to redirect from any page with any parameters, so have can i know about parameters of any request?

Comment: You need to know about parameters of the destination view previously. Obviously, you can leave them empty, but you need the destination view to be prepared for that case.

Comment: so i can't make action method to change language on any page (with some parameters too) and come back to same page with parameters?

Comment: Of course you can. Use f:view with the locale attribute and set it a parameter based value.

Comment: i think you don't understand me: i have a lot of pages with deferents parameters and one template page with `h:commandButton` with `action` to session scope bean with method, where i set locale. For different pages i have different parameters, but to change language i always use same `h:commandButton`. So I can't add `f:param` to `h:commandButton` because I don't know what parameter i get for current page, am I right?

Comment: If main template includes the `f:view` bound to the session bean you don't need to receive parameters in your destination page at all. All page will inherit from that `f:view`, when pages are reloaded, the locale value will be changed, so don't need to pass it as a view parameter. I think you're mixing Session parameters with GET parameters in this case. If you want a more specifc answer please post another thread with a more elaborated question according to your problem, as you didn't mention neither templates or languages at all in your original one. I think my answer suits for the original.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
return currentURL + "?faces-redirect=true&includeViewParams=true";
```