# <f:setPropertyActionListener> Parent is not of type ActionSource, type is: com.sun.faces.component.PassthroughElement

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, passthrough-elements, setpropertyactionlistener

I'm using Passthrough elements in my JSF project, and need to do something similar to this:

```
<h:commandLink action="#{myBean.acao()}" value="click me">
        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{myBean.object}" value="#{localObject}"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

but using Passthrough elements to have more control of my frontend like trying below:

```
<a href="#" jsf:action="#{myBean.acao()}">click me
        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{myBean.object}" value="#{localObject}"/>
</a>
```

but apparently this is not working, I get the following error message:

```
<f:setPropertyActionListener> Parent is not of type ActionSource, type is: com.sun.faces.component.PassthroughElement
```

Does anyone know how I could solve this?

Comment: thanks for the correction of terms @BalusC. I'll see if my version is equal to this!

Comment: thanks for the help, switched to version 2.2.12 and it worked! @BalusC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like just a bug in your Mojarra version. It works for me with current latest 2.2.12 version.

You could workaround it by utilizing the EL 2.2 feature of passing method arguments. See also [Invoke direct methods or methods with arguments / variables / parameters in EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284236/invoke-direct-methods-or-methods-with-arguments-variables-parameters-in-el). It's surely available in your environment as `#{myBean.acao()}` apparently didn't throw an EL exception (this syntax is not supported before EL 2.2).

```
<a href="#" jsf:action="#{myBean.acao(localObject)}">click me</a>
```

If you absolutely need to invoke a setter during an action listener event, e.g. because you'd like to control the invocation of `action` by throwing `AbortProcessingException` in case the set value is invalid, see also [Differences between action and actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener), then declare a `jsf:actionListener`.

```
<a href="#" jsf:actionListener="#{myBean.setObject(localObject)}" jsf:action="#{myBean.acao}">click me</a>
```

Comment: thanks for the help, switched to version 2.2.12 and it worked! @BalusC

Comment: You're welcome. For the record, which version did you initially use? Then I can if necessary lookup the associated issue report and bugfix version in the tracker.

Comment: I was using version 2.2.1 @BalusC

Comment: We frequently and completely randomly get the mentioned exception with Mojarra 2.1.28 and previous ones. Does anyone know the bug that fixed this in Mojarra?