# How to reference a method in EL which does not meet naming convention

Tags: jsf, el, method-reference

Java `List` type does not have a `getSize()` method. Is there a way to tell reference the `size()` method in EL instead? I've tried `#{aList.size > 10}` but that is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do `#{aList.size() > 10}` (suffix the method with parentheses).

Comment: Noted should be that this requires a minimum of EL 2.2, but based on OP's question history OP is already using that. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/3284236