# Java Beans - how to ignore boolean isXXXXMethod in favor of BOOLEAN getXXXXMethod in JSF page?

Tags: jsf-2, javabeans

I have this MyHumbleTO which attribute is read on a JSF page. So I need to add `isTheAwesomeBoolean` Method to use elsewhere. But now the page is reading that new method instead the get method, which is inappropriate. Is there a way to ignore that in page?

```
<h:outputText value="#{myAwesomeBean.myHumbleTO.theAwesomeBoolean ne null ? 
                    (myAwesomeBean.myHumbleTO.theAwesomeBoolean ? 'Yes ' : 'No') : ''}" />


public class MyHumbleTO implements Serializable{

    private Boolean theAwesomeBoolean;

    public boolean isTheAwesomeBoolean() {
        return Boolean.TRUE.equals(theAwesomeBoolean);
    }

    public Boolean getTheAwesomeBoolean() {
        return theAwesomeBoolean;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With recent EL (Version >= 2.2) just use `getTheAwesomeBoolean()` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3284328/3994580) for details).

In the given example:

```
<h:outputText value="#{myAwesomeBean.myHumbleTO.getTheAwesomeBoolean() ne null ? 
        (myAwesomeBean.myHumbleTO.theAwesomeBoolean ? 'Yes ' : 'No') : ''}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, If you'd try to debug this, you will find out, that this is all about EL implementation, not JSF.

Since there is [a right answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73785974/1411160) from [DaniEll](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3994580/daniell) for exactly what you pasted in XHTML, I'll answer differently.

**No, there is no way** to *favor* one or another. Especially it will never work if you would like to use this in an input. You cannot bind `value` property like that. And I'd avoid mixing simple types with class types in such cases (boolean/Boolean, int/Integer etc.).